# T-SQL select matching rows from multiple columns delimited by carriage returns (BGInfo output)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xml-parsing, sql-server-2012

BGInfo (Microsoft Sysinternals) has the ability to write data to a SQL server.  The network card information is one field, delimited by CRLF CHAR(13)+CHAR(10).  Some computers may only have one network card.  Others may have 7 or maybe more network cards.  Each field (Network_Card, IP_Address and Subnet_Mask) contains a CRLF-delimited list of the matching network card information.

[image]

I want to convert the CRLF delimited fields into multiple rows matching the 1st entry of Network_Card with the 1st entry of IP_Address and Subnet_Mask.   And then, select the records where the Default_Gateway matches the IP_address (indicating which network card is active).

BGInfo populates many fields into the table, for this example I will create a subset using the desired fields.

So first we can create a temporary BGInfo table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BGInfo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BGInfo
CREATE TABLE #BGInfo (
    [User_Name]         nvarchar(25),
    [Host_Name]         nvarchar(25),
    [Network_Card]      nvarchar(MAX),
    [IP_Address]        nvarchar(255),
    [Subnet_Mask]       nvarchar(255),
    [Default_Gateway]   nvarchar(25)
)
```

Then populate it with some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO #BGInfo
SELECT
    'User1',
    'PC-A',
    'nic1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic2'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic3'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic4'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic5'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic6'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic7',
    '(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'10.91.2.155'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'192.168.80.1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'192.168.126.1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)',
    '(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'255.255.255.128'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'255.255.255.0'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'255.255.255.0'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)',
    '10.91.2.129'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'User2',
    'PC-B',
    'nic1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic2'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic3'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic4'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic5'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic6'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'nic7',
    '10.17.17.23'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'192.168.80.1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'192.168.126.1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)',
    '255.255.240.0'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'255.255.255.0'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'255.255.255.0'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'(none)',
    '10.17.16.5'
```

I figured that if I converted the CRLF to comma-separated-values:

```
REPLACE([IP_Address],CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),',')
```

I could then convert that to XML and select the rows. (lots of info online for this) But... how would that work with multiple columns?   I have tried this, but it just creates a lot of repeated data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XMLtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XMLtable
CREATE TABLE #XMLtable (
    [User_Name]     nvarchar(25),
    Computer        nvarchar(25),
    Network_Card    nvarchar(255),
    IPAddr          xml,
    Subnet          xml,
    Default_Gateway nvarchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #XMLtable
SELECT
    [User_Name],
    [Host_Name] as Computer,
    [Network_Card],
    CAST('<i>'+REPLACE(REPLACE([IP_Address],CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),','),',','</i><i>')+'</i>' as xml) AS IPAddr,
    CAST('<i>'+REPLACE(REPLACE([Subnet_Mask],CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),','),',','</i><i>')+'</i>' as xml) AS Subnet,
    Default_Gateway
 FROM #BGInfo bg

 SELECT
    [User_Name],
    [Computer],
    [Network_Card],
    IP_Address = i.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),
    IP_Address = s.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),
    Default_Gateway
FROM #XMLtable
CROSS APPLY IPaddr.nodes ('/i') AS IPAddr(i)
CROSS APPLY Subnet.nodes ('/i') AS Subnet(s);
```

I would like to have a list something like this: (data may not match but you get the idea)

```
User_Name   Computer    Network_Card    IP_Address  Subnet_Mask     Default_Gateway
User1       PC-A        nic1        (none)  (none)  10.91.2.129
User1       PC-A        nic2        (none)  (none)  10.91.2.129
User1       PC-A        nic3        10.91.2.155 255.255.255.128 10.91.2.129
User1       PC-A        nic4        192.168.80.1    255.255.255.0   10.91.2.129
User1       PC-A        nic5        192.168.126.1   255.255.255.0   10.91.2.129
User2       PC-B        nic1        10.17.17.23 255.255.240.0   10.17.16.5
User2       PC-B        nic2        (none)  (none)  10.17.16.5
User2       PC-B        nic3        (none)  (none)  10.17.16.5
User2       PC-B        nic4        192.168.80.1    255.255.255.0   10.17.16.5
User2       PC-B        nic5        192.168.126.1   255.255.255.0   10.17.16.5
```

And then be able to select the ACTIVE network cards where the default gateway matches the IP_address:

```
User_Name   Computer    Network_CardIP_Address  Subnet_Mask Default_Gateway
User1       PC-A        nic3            10.91.2.155 255.255.255.128 10.91.2.129
User2       PC-B        nic1            10.17.17.23 255.255.240.0   10.17.16.5
```

Comment: Wow...thats a long question Kudos on providing all the info.

Comment: There will be about 8000+ Computers and 30 days worth of data, so I'm guessing there will be about 250,000 records, of which I will usually filter for just the most recent logon.  So efficiency is desirable (isn't it always?)

Comment: I hope you get an answer but splitting out three (and syncing them up) is going to be the hard part.  I would do this in .NET.

Comment: It may help to add the datetime field of the login, which should be unique for each computer/user logon yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000.

Comment: It is already complex enough.  If you you datetime then put it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trouble comes from trying to break out the cards, ips, and subnets from the single #XMLtable table.  Using the same logic you did, I made three separate queries (one each for network cards, ips, and subnets), generating row_numbers for each one, and joining them together based on the row_number.  Then I used `PARSENAME` to compare the ip address and the gateway.

```
select nics.User_Name, 
nics.Host_Name Computer, 
nics.nic Network_Card, 
ips.ip IP_Address, 
subnets.subnet Subnet_Mask, 
b.Default_Gateway
from
(
    select User_Name, Host_Name,
    nic.a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as nic,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by User_name, Host_name order by User_name, Host_name) Row_number
    from 
    (
        select b.User_name, b.Host_name, 
        CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(b.Network_Card, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml) as nics
        from #BGInfo b
    ) a
    cross apply nics.nodes('/i') as nic(a)
) nics
join
(
    select User_Name, Host_Name,
    ip.a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as ip,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by User_name, Host_name order by User_name, Host_name) Row_number
    from 
    (
        select b.User_name, b.Host_name, 
        CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(b.IP_Address, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml) as ips
        from #BGInfo b
    ) a
    cross apply ips.nodes('/i') as ip(a)
) ips on ips.User_Name = nics.User_Name and ips.Host_Name = nics.Host_Name and ips.Row_number = nics.Row_number
join
(
    select User_Name, Host_Name,
    subnet.a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as subnet,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by User_name, Host_name order by User_name, Host_name) Row_number
    from 
    (
        select b.User_name, b.Host_name, 
        CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(b.Subnet_Mask, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml) as subnets
        from #BGInfo b
    ) a
    cross apply subnets.nodes('/i') as subnet(a)
) subnets on subnets.User_Name = nics.User_Name and subnets.Host_Name = nics.Host_Name and subnets.Row_number = nics.Row_number
join #BGInfo b on b.User_Name = nics.User_Name and b.Host_Name = nics.Host_Name
where PARSENAME(ips.ip, 4) = PARSENAME(b.Default_Gateway, 4) and
PARSENAME(ips.ip, 3) = PARSENAME(b.Default_Gateway, 3)
```

I don't know how it will perform against a large number of rows, but it works for the test data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36304/0)

Comment: Thanks @Jerrad - I was working on something similar using 3 #temp tables.  I like the use of PARSENAME. I will play with this and post an update.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to dump BGInfo, and use a PowerShell script.  Powershell can get Nic info, and it can execute SQL.  If your desktops have PowerShell installed, then this maybe easier to build and maintain, and probably faster.
I found two articles that could help get you there:

1. get nic info:
   http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-get-ip-address-subnet-gateway-dns-serves-and-mac-address-details-of-remote-computer/1367
2. save to db:
   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1463926-1351-1.aspx

If you have to use BGInfo then, personally, I would take a different approach, and separate the concerns.

1. allow BGInfo to write to SQL in the simplest, most out-of-the-box way (i.e. populating the multiple IP addresses into one delimited column
2. create a related table that will contain the parsed nic + IP address info.
3. create a simple program (not SQL, more like C# for example) that churns through the unprocessed rows in the BGInfo table, parsing out the nic + IP address info to the related table.

If the unique key on the BGInfoTable is Time_stamp + User_name + Host_name, then you can have a related nic table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BGInfo_Nics (
   BGTime_Stamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
   User_Name NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, -- these cols should match BGInfoTable datatypes
   Host_Name NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   NicName NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, 
   IPAddress NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
   SubNet  NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
   GatewayIP NVARCHAR(50) NULL
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_BGInfo_Nics ON BGInfo_Nics ( BGTime_Stamp,
    User_Name,
    Host_Name,
    NicName
)
GO
```

The program would run constantly, and every so often, it could query the BGInfoTable to see if there are rows it needs to process.  Processing would consist of reading the rows yet to process from the BGInfoTable, parsing the nic information including IP address, subnet and gateway, and writing the nic info rows to the new (related) table BGInfo_Nics.

e.g.:  -- use this to get the rows need to process:

```
SELECT bg.*
FROM BGInfoTable bg (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN BGInfo_Nics nics  (NOLOCK) ON 
bg.Time_Stamp = nics.BGTime_Stamp AND
bg.[User_Name] = nics.[User_name] AND
bg.[Host_Name] = nics.[Host_name]
WHERE nics.BGTime_Stamp IS NULL
```

Alternatively, you could add a couple of columns to the BGInfoTable to mark which rows have been processed already and create an index to get the unprocessed rows quickly.

Having a separate program do the processing (read new, parse and save), I suspect that this kind of solution will provide more flexibility in parsing and saving the data into the format you really want for reporting, and will perform very well.

HTH

Mike

Comment: Sadly we can't use Powershell and I don't know C# but you do have some useful ideas here.  Thanks!